# PrimeNg Calendar date not working properly

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, primeng, angular7

I create a new angular 7 project by Angular CLI and I create new C# project. I didn't make any additional configuration both client and server side. And I create a form like below. But my date going to my c# class as 3 hour back. Forexample, I choose '03/28/2019' , but I'm taking as '03/27/2019 21:00.00' . I tried by `showTime` property of calendar. But, result not changed. How I can solve this problem?

**You should look the stackblitz console not browser console.** In additionally, when I changed `<p-calendar formControlName="birthdate"></p-calendar>` by `<input type="date" formControlName="birthdate">` , then it's working perfectly. **So, I think there is no problem in my server.**(both server and client is same. It's my computer)

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sew3em)

**.html file**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
  <p-calendar formControlName="birthdate"></p-calendar>  <br><br>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**.ts file**

```
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, public http: HttpClient) { }

  myForm = this.fb.group({
    birthdate: [null],
  });

  save() {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/values', this.myForm.value).subscribe(result => {
    });
  }
```

**C# .cs file**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void Post([FromBody] MyObject value)
 {
 }

 public class MyObject
 {
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Sounds like a timezone problem, are you by any chance in a GMT+3 or GMT-3 timezone

Comment: My timezone is GMT+03:00 . But it's no problem in html date input. @MikNiller

Comment: Your timezone and your hour offset is identical, that would make me suspicius. Take a look at your browsers developer/network tool to inspect what is actually transmitted from angular to c#

Comment: When I looked my network tab in my chrome developer tool, I'm seeing `2019-03-27T21:00:00.000Z` . @MikNiller

Comment: Then i suspect that your control is handling the date in local time (but without including the timezone), when it is transfered to the backend it is then converted to UTC, but because the timezone part is missing , you are loosing three hours

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution .Primeng calendar has a property `dataType` . DataType is `date` in default. If you set `string` instead of `date`, then it's working perfectly and sending correct date to server.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtwv43)

You can see from working example from this stackblitz link.

Comment: but my backed is expecting iso formate and string is not acceptable so any solution?